# My flair not updated

Tags: discussion, flair

Hi I have to apply dark theme flair but it is not updated (**Reputation**) from last 2 days.

**Show image Below:**

[image]

Comment: [Your flair](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2W5of.png) looks fine to me.

Comment: @Azik see the dark theme flair reputation is not updated on it.

Comment: @MD - He show you the picture of the dark theme. Didn't he?

Comment: @hims056 well, for the OP here it's showing the old reputation (the live flair I mean). The cache is per user as far as I remember.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I knew that. All I meant to say was caching!